# Can’t obtain IP address with netctl

Tags: networking, arch-linux, network-interface, netctl

I have the bare minimum Arch Linux install with a wired connection. I can’t seem to obtain an IP address with netctl. I created an eth0 profile with ethernet-dhcp. I tried to start the profile but the control process exited with error code. When I look at the status of netctl it says it exited with error code. I can restart netctl but it still has the same error. What can I do to figure out why I can’t get an IP with netctl?

Comment: Could you add the error code and the content of `/etc/netctl/Your_profile`

Comment: I ended up switching back to dhcpcd

Answer (score 2):

Check if you correctly specified DHCP in the IP field and a valid DHCPClient in the netctl profile you are using:

file: `/etc/netctl/ethernet-dhcp` (see [netctl example profiles](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/netctl#Example_profiles) for more examples)

```
Description='A Basic DHCP Ethernet Connection'
Interface=enp30s0 (use your interface name here, this is the one in my system)
Connection=ethernet
IP=dhcp
DHCPClient=dhcpcd
```

If **dhcpcd** doesn't work for you you can try using **dhclient**

As mentioned by [@bsautner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703937/313704) you might actually be missing both of these tools, if you have correctly setup Pacman on your system you should be able to just execute:

```
sudo pacman -S dhcpcd
sudo pacman -S dhclient
```

Another way of fixing this might be to bypass netctl and just launch dhcpcd/dhclient to configure the interface for you on the spot.

The [netctl documentation for DHCP troubleshooting on the archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl#DHCP_Troubleshooting) might also help.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum install of arch is just that, it's missing everything.

I found this when I ran
 `sudo netctl is-active ethernet-dhcp` and got the status `failed`

Facepalm moment: Install dhcpcd first!

```
sudo pacman -S dhcpcd
```